# Compound "OR" evaluation in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I've searched the forums and found a few related threads but no definitive answer.

```
(case
when field1 LIKE '%T001%' OR field1 LIKE '%T201%' OR field1 LIKE '%T301%'...
```

In the above statement, if field1 is "like" t001, will the others even be evaluated?

```
(case
when (field1 LIKE '%T001%' OR field1 LIKE '%T201%' OR field1 LIKE '%T301%')...
```

Does adding parenthesis as shown above change the evaluation?

Answer (score 1):

In general, databases short-circuit boolean operations.  That is, they stop at the first value that defines the result -- the first "true" for `OR`, the first "false" for `AND`.

That said, there are no guarantees.  Nor are there guarantees about the order of evaluation.  So, DB2 could decide to test the middle, the last, and then the first.  That said, these are pretty equivalent, so I would expect the ordering to be either first to last or last to first.

Remember:  SQL is a *descriptive* language, not a *procedural* language.  A SQL query describers the result set, but not the steps used to generate it.

Comment: Thanks.  Will adding the parenthetis force the evaluation of the field each value which is the desired result?  Or do I need to put the parenthesis around each comparison: (field1 LIKE  value) OR (field2 like value)?  The other option is putting each on a new line (when field1 like "t001"... when field1 like "t002"...)

Comment: @JobbieDaddy . . . No.  Adding parentheses affects the *meaning* of the expressions (although in this case they are unnecessary).  The optimizer is still free to re-arrange the *evaluation* in any order consistent with the *meaning*.

Comment: _Nor are there guarantees about the order of evaluation_ in this particular statement...since only one operator is being used...generally though you are guaranteed that multiple operators will be evaluated in order of precedence.   Which I know @GordonLinoff is well aware of...

Answer (score 1):

You don't know.

SQL is a *declarative* language, not an *imperative* one. You describe what you want, the engine provides it. The database engine will decide in which sequence it will evaluate those predicates, and you don't have control over that.

If you get the execution plan today it may show one sequence of steps, but if you get it tomorrow it may show something different.

Comment: Thanks.  Does adding the parenthetis force the evaluation of each which  is the desired result?  Or do I need to put the parenthesis around each: (field1 LIKE  value) OR (field2 like value)?

Comment: @JobbieDaddy Not sure, but I would bet those parenthesis won't make any difference. DB2's parser includes a "rephrase" phase where it actually internally rewrites/simplifies the query to make it cheaper; all dirty tricks there are game, so I would assume one of the first things it will do is to "get rid" of all unnecessary parenthesis. But this is just a guess.

Comment: Thanks again.  Is the  the safest bet to evaluate individually?  when (field1 LIKE '%T001%') then "22", when (field1 LIKE '%T002%') then "23"

Comment: Why are you trying to optimize it yourself? Let DB2 do the optimization. It usually does a far better job that you can do. Plus, in time when the data changes, it'll automatically adapt to new conditions, while your hardcoded query won't. The engine is quite sophisticated.

Comment: I'm not trying to optimize per say.  The current query is producing skewed results and seems like it is not evaluating for all OR's...  I am trying to force it to.

Comment: Provide sample data that reproduces the case, and we can help.

Comment: @JobbieDaddy your overall query might be incorrect, or your assumptions invalid etc. Sometimes there are bugs, but in those cases, exhaustive details about your environment/configuration/runstats/queryopt etc become necessary to know.

Comment: Surely there is a way to evaluate the same field for various values consistently within a case statement?  That's all I am wanting to do here.  My statement uses several tables and personal client information is involved so sharing the data  won't be easy.

Comment: In the interest of time I am just going to evaluate individually (on a new line  "when...") although I feel like there should be a more elegant way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly answering your question, but if you have many of these matches, a simpler, possibly faster, and easier to maintain solution would be to use [`REGEXP_LIKE`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061494.html). The example you've posted could be written like this:

```sql
CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(field1, '.*T(0|2|3)01.*') ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for indication how it really works in this simple case.

```
select
  field1
, case
  when field1 LIKE '%T001%' OR RAISE_ERROR('75000', '%T201%') LIKE '%T201%' then 1 else 0
  end as expr
from 
(
values 
  'abcT001xyz'
--, '***'
) t (field1);
```

The query returns expected result for the statement above as is.
But if you uncomment the commented out line, you get `SQLCODE=-438`.
This means, that 2-nd OR operand is not evaluated, if 1-st returns `true`.
Note, that it's just for demonstration. There is no any guarantee, that this will work in such a way in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to some points made about the difference between so-called procedural languages on the one hand, and SQL (which is variously described as a declarative or descriptive language) on the other.

SQL defines a set of relatively high-level operators for working with arrays of data. They are "high-level" in this sense because they work with arrays in a concise fashion that has not been typical of general purpose or procedural languages. Like all operators (whether array-based or not), there is typically more than one algorithm capable of implementing an operator.

In contrast to "general purpose" programming languages to which the vast majority of programmers are exposed, the existence of these array operators - in particular, the ability to combine them algebraically into an expression which defines a composite operation (or a query), and the absence of any explicit algorithms for iteration - was once a defining feature of SQL.

The distinction is less sharp nowadays, with a resurgent interest in functional languages and features, but most still view SQL as a beast of its own kind amongst commercially-popular tooling.

It is often said that in SQL you define *what* results you want not *how* to get them. But this is true for every language. It is true even for machine code operators, if you account for how the implementation in circuitry can be varied - and does vary, between CPU designs. It is certainly true for all compiled languages, where compilers employ many different machine code algorithms to actually implement operations specified in the source code - loop unrolling, for one example.

The feature which continues to distinguish SQL (and the relational databases which implement it), is that the algorithm which implements an operation is *determined at the time of each execution*, and it does this not just by algebraic manipulation of queries (which is not dissimilar to what compilers do), but also by continuously generating and analysing *statistics* about the data being operated upon and the consequences of previous executions.

Put another way, the database execution engine is engaged in a constant *search* for the best practical algorithms (and combinations thereof) to implement its overall workload. It is capable of accomodating not just past experience, but of reacting to changes (such as in data volumes, in degree of concurrency and transactional conflict, or in systemic constraints like available memory or overall workload).

The upshot of all this is that there is a specific order of evaluation in SQL, just like any other language. It is this order which defines a correct result. But unless written in so-called RBAR style (and even then, but to a more limited extent...), the database engine has tremendous latitude to implement shortcuts and performance optimisations, provided these do not change the final result.

Many operators fall into a class where it is possible to determine the result in many cases without evaluating all operands. I'm not sure what the formal word is to describe this property - *partial evaluativity*, maybe - but casually it is called *short-circuiting*. The OR operator has this property.

Another property of the OR operation is that it is *associative*. That is, the order in which a series of them are applied does not matter - it behaves like the addition operator does, where you can add numbers in any order without affecting the result.

With a series of OR conditions, these are capable of being reordered and partially evaluated, provided the evaluation of any particular operand does not cause side-effects or depend on hidden variables. It is therefore quite likely that the database engine may reorder or partially evaluate them.

If the operands do cause side-effects or depend on hidden variables (functions which get the current date or time being a prime example of the latter), these often cause problems in queries - either because the database engine does not realise they have side-effects or hidden variables, or because the database does realise it but doesn't handle the case in the way the programmer expects. In such cases, a query may have to be completely rewritten (typically, cracked into multiple statements) to force a specific evaluation order or guarantee full evaluation.